# how to read a Blob in D3.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, azure-blob-storage

I need to download a blob, then read the values and create D3 charts. So far I managed to download the blob file from Azure container. But I don't know how to get the values from it and give it to the d3.js. How much I know, D3 can read CSV files, so I tried to convert the blob to CSV file but didn't work. Is there a way to do this ?
thanks !

```
const AzureService = {
  execute: async function() {
    const accountName = STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME;
    const blobName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    const sasString = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    const containerName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    const containerURL = new azblob.ContainerURL(
      `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}?${sasString}`,
      azblob.StorageURL.newPipeline(new azblob.AnonymousCredential())
    );
    const blobURL = azblob.BlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL, blobName);

    const downloadBlobResponse = await blobURL.download(azblob.Aborter.none, 0);
    return await downloadBlobResponse.blobBody;
  }
};
```

getting the blob in the service

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.file = AzureService.execute().then(data => {
    this.readCSVs(data);
  });
}
```

There I'm trying to convert the blob and use D3.csv to read

```
readCSVs(data) {
  let contentType = "text/csv";
  let csvFile = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });

  let svg, productName, filtered;
  d3.csv(csvFile).then(data => {
    svg = d3
      .select("#users_bar2")
      .style("width", 500)
      .style("height", 500);

    productName = "CLeg";
    filtered = data.filter(x => x.productName == productName);
    this.histogram(svg, filtered, 500, 500, "hist", productName);
  });
}
```

Comment: What's the format of the data stored in blob?

Comment: its a .csv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation available [`here`](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#csv), you can use `d3.csv` file to read directly from the blob (no need for a separate function to read from Azure Blob Storage).

```
d3.csv(`https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}?${sasString}`, row, callback)
```

where

```
row: parser function to parse a record (row) into JSON format

callback: callback function
```